# Delete all documents in a CouchDB database *except* the design documents

Tags: couchdb

Is it possible to delete all documents in a couchdb database, *except* design documents, without creating a specific view for that?

My first approach has been to access the `_all_docs` standard view, and discard those documents starting with `_design`. This works but, for large databases, is too slow, since the documents need to be requested from the database (in order to get the document revision) one at a time.

If this is the only valid approach, I think it is much more practical to delete the complete database, and create it from scratch inserting the design documents again.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I can think of a couple of ideas.

### Use _all_docs

You do not need to fetch all the *documents*, only the ID and revisions. By default, that is all that _all_docs returns. You can make a pretty big request in a batch (10k or 100k docs at a time should be fine).

### Replicate then delete

You could use an `_all_docs` query to get the IDs of all design documents.

```
GET /db/_all_docs?startkey="_design/"&endkey="_design0"
```

Then replicate them somewhere temporary.

```
POST /_replicator

{ "source":"db", "target":"db_ddocs", "create_target":true
, "user_ctx": {"roles":["_admin"]}
, "doc_ids": ["_design/ddoc_1", "_design/ddoc_2", "etc..."]
}
```

Now you can just delete the original database and replicate the temporary one back by swapping the `"source"` and `"target"` values.

### Deleting vs "deleting"

Note, these are really apples vs. oranges techniques. By deleting a *database*, you are wiping out the edit history of all its documents. In other words, you cannot replicate those deletion events to any other database. When you "delete" a document in CouchDB, it stores a record of that deletion. If you replicate that database, those deletions will be reflected in the target. (CouchDB stores "tombstones" indicating the document ID, its revision history, and its deleted state.)

That may or may not be important to you. The first idea is probably considered more "correct" however I can see the value of the second. You can visualize the entire program to accomplish this in your head. It's only a few queries and you're done. No looping through `_all_docs` batches, no headache. Your specific situation will probably make it obvious which is better.

Comment: Very detailed, thanks. There is also another option which I think has worked for me in the past: stop couchdb and delete the database in the filesystem. If I recall correctly, the view documents are stored somewhere else. Please correct me if I am wrong (no possibilty to check now).

Answer (score 2):

Install couchapp, pull down the design doc to your hard disk, delete the db in futon, push the design doc back up to your recreated database. =)

Answer (score 1):

You could write a shell script that goes through the list of all documents and deletes them all one by one except design docs. Apparently [couch-batch](https://github.com/dsp/couch-batch) can do that. Note that you don't need to fetch the whole docs to do that, just the id and revision.

Other than that, I think [filtered replication](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Replication#Filtered_Replication) (or the replication proposed by JasonSmith) is your best bet.